Is it safe for a young female to transit at Seoul Incheon at night?
Our daughter (17) will transit through Seoul and have a 7 hour interval between the planes, at night. She needs to collect luggage, go through immigration (no visa should be required) and check in again, and will likely have to wait for a while before she can check in and go through security. Is this safe, and are there things she should be aware of or pay special attention to?

This might get closed as opinion-based because there's no single universal definition of "safe". However, the terminal of a major airport is perhaps the safest place on Earth. There are surveillance cameras literally watching your every step. And then there's wireless location tracking and likely other stuff that's not publicly known.

Especially air-side. Random chancers can't go there, but in the public land-side areas there may be opportunists, like at railway stations etc.

In practice she probably only has about 3 hours to wait around, allowing say 1 hour to deplane / clear immigration / reclaim baggage on arrival, and deducting say 3 hours for check-in / baggage drop for her next flight. Travelling alone I find the biggest challenges between flights are not falling asleep and navigating toilet cubicles with luggage.

There are similar questions about other airports e.g. Tokyo Haneda, Cairo, Bamako, which all conclude that airports are fairly safe (a bit less so in war zones). You can search for others but there are a lot of false positives (questions about connection times, COVID, etc).

My only concern were it my daughter would be if the person in question is excessively shy and would resist asking for directions to a gate or whatever. A short connection would be more worrisome. She'll get on her phone or iPad and the time will fly by.

Answering my own question just to confirm that she did travel and apparently did not feel unsafe in the airport, although I made her seriously confused trying to guide her towards the right terminal by phone while looking at a map of the wrong airport in Seoul.. all my fault.
I appreciate all comments and reassurance here.
